# How to make a zoom between two marker in maps

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

i try  to make a zoom in two markers in maps with flutter but i didn't find a method in flutter fitBounds.

```
  getRouteCoordinates(_initialPosition, destination);
  *LatLngBounds bound = LatLngBounds(northeast: initialPosition,southwest: destination);


      //mapController.getVisibleRegion();
    CameraUpdate u2 = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bound, 10);
    this.mapController.animateCamera(u2).then((void v){
      check(u2,this.mapController);
    });


  void check(CameraUpdate u, GoogleMapController c) async {
    c.animateCamera(u);
    mapController.animateCamera(u);
    LatLngBounds l1=await c.getVisibleRegion();
    LatLngBounds l2=await c.getVisibleRegion();
    print(l1.toString());
    print(l2.toString());
    if(l1.southwest.latitude==-90 ||l2.southwest.latitude==-90)
      check(u, c);
   }
```

Comment: did you find an way to do this?

Comment: yes it's works for me now

Comment: LatLngBounds boundsFromLatLngList(List<LatLng> list) {
    assert(list.isNotEmpty);
    double x0, x1, y0, y1;
    for (LatLng latLng in list) {
      if (x0 == null) {
        x0 = x1 = latLng.latitude;
        y0 = y1 = latLng.longitude;
      } else {
        if (latLng.latitude > x1) x1 = latLng.latitude;
        if (latLng.latitude < x0) x0 = latLng.latitude;
        if (latLng.longitude > y1) y1 = latLng.longitude;
        if (latLng.longitude < y0) y0 = latLng.longitude;
      }
    }
    return LatLngBounds(northeast: LatLng(x1, y1), southwest: LatLng(x0, y0));
  }

Comment: this methode return bounds from list markers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly ,make a list from your GeoPoint,and make a function to choose the Point of Bounds.

```
LatLngBounds boundsFromLatLngList(List<LatLng> list) {
assert(list.isNotEmpty);
double x0, x1, y0, y1;
for (LatLng latLng in list) {
  if (x0 == null) {
    x0 = x1 = latLng.latitude;
    y0 = y1 = latLng.longitude;
  } else {
    if (latLng.latitude > x1) x1 = latLng.latitude;
    if (latLng.latitude < x0) x0 = latLng.latitude;
    if (latLng.longitude > y1) y1 = latLng.longitude;
    if (latLng.longitude < y0) y0 = latLng.longitude;
  }
}
return LatLngBounds(northeast: LatLng(x1, y1), southwest: LatLng(x0, y0));
}
```

After That Call this function and make zoom

```
  LatLngBounds bound = boundsFromLatLngList(listmap);
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds:500)).then((v) async {
  CameraUpdate u2 = CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bound, 50);
  this.mapController.animateCamera(u2).then((void v) {
    check(u2, this.mapController);
  });
});
```

This snippet for code is work for me